# APK file size and Android Studio APK building process

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I realized that, for some reason, Android Studio produces differently sized APK files than when I'm doing it *manually* using Gradle.

So, when I build file with Gradle (either `gradle build` or `gradle assembleDebug`) I am getting apks sized depending on whether I have activated ProGuard or not.

Without ProGuard I get a file with around 62k method references. With ProGuard activated I get an apk file with around 37k method references and 6mb heavy. And that seems okay.

But! When I run an app from Android Studio (with ProGuard activated), I get an apk file that is heavy around 3mb and, when imported for analysis has two dex files (`classes.dex` and `classes2.dex`), and both of them together shows only 300 method references, which is, obviously, not correct.

And app works normally no matter which way I've built it, I haven't seen any irregularities.

So, how and why does it happen? I tried to google little bit about how Android Studio does building process, but without success. I assumed that it essentially shouldn't make file any different than one I make calling `gradle build`, but obviously that is not the case.

I am using Gradle 3.3 (as Gradle Wrapper) and Android Studio 2.3.3.

This are some numbers that might be relevant:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 25
```

Comment: Android Studio is making a multidex APK for you. BTW, you should compare with the same version of Gradle that Android Studio uses, which is usually through the provided Gradle wrapper (gradlew) rather than whatever version of Gradle runs when you invoke the gradle command. This might explain why you don't (or do you?) get a multidex APK when you invoke Gradle directly.

Comment: Get tool "dx" and dump disassebly of all methods in files in both cases. Compare files.

Comment: @jdv I *was* using local gradlew, the same one AS is using. And when zou say "AS is making multidex apk", is that like normal behavior, or it is triggered by something particular? And why would it show only 300 methods?

Comment: @bukkojot Will try.

Comment: @SadClown, you should update your question. It clearly shows you running `gradle` and not the wrapper script. Hence, my comment. This is an important piece of information.

Comment: I would suggest updating the question with the version of Android Studio and Gradle it is using in the body of the question.

Comment: @SadClown see here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html The assumption is you are using a later API level, so Android Studio is making APKs suitable for running on an ART runtime, but that is a guess. However, you should post your `build.gradle` so we can stare at it, because I think you still need to enable multidex there. Alternatively, this might be a symptom of the API level and a newer Android Studio. Perhaps the recent Instant Run changes result in multidex APKs? Just a guess.

Comment: @jdv I've edited my post as you've suggested. I have not enabled multidex in gradle, since I don't go over 64k methods. Is there any other reason to do so?

Answer (score 1):

APK compile using the manual Run button on Android Studio, is optimized specifically for the device it is targeted only, while the APK compiled using gradle command, could be used to target any other devices. Check out

https://medium.com/@elye.project/manual-compile-produces-smaller-apk-size-from-command-line-gradle-compile-6cc08d98f2be

https://medium.com/@elye.project/dont-publish-your-manually-compiled-apk-c8ce2bf7e6b4

Not sure about why your APK is only 300 method references.